# Why do i keep getting a bad input error regarding this string statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I have a syntax error that I am confused on within my python code

```
deliveryValue= input("Is this order for delivery? Y/N")
float (DeliveryTime = 0)
str (zipcode=none)
float (DeliveryFee =0)
if deliveryValue == 'y' or 'Y':
    address = input ("what is the delivery address?")
    zipcode = input ("What zipcode is the address in?")
        if zipcode == 84041:
            DeliveryTime = 30
            DeliveryFee = 6.50
        else:
            DeliveryTime = 45
            DeliveryFee = 7.50
else:
    DeliveryFee = 0
```

the if zipcode == 84041: line comes out with an error, however I have tried placing ' ' and " " around it and still has the same error. Am i writing this correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if deliveryValue == 'y' or 'Y':` does not do what you think it does. This will always evaluate to `True`. Use `if deliveryValue.lower() == 'y':` to make it case-independent

Comment: `if zipcode == 84041:` should have same indentation as previous line `zipcode = input...`

Comment: `float (DeliveryTime = 0)` also isnt correct since you're performing an assignment. I actually don't know what this is intended to do, though

Comment: I don't mean this in a harsh way (I apologise) but so far I can see issues in lines 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9-13 (indentation), in addition to things like PEP8 issues throughout. I think you'd be better taking a step back here and building this incrementally from scratch, ensuring that you know that each point works and you understand why. There's nothing wrong with pushing yourself, but these issues are going to compound themselves and make it _so_ much harder for you to understand what's happening when it's going on at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your if statement to

```
if deliveryValue in 'yY':
```

you can also use

```
if deliveryValue == 'y' or deliveryValue  == 'Y':
```

Comment: The more I look, the more issues there are. This falls way short of giving them workable code. I think it's probably too broad.

Comment: that if statement is good it's the if statement within that one that is causing me trouble

Comment: @S.S. That `if` does _not_ work for you currently, you've presumably just not come across a case yet where it gives unexpected output

Comment: ok i see what you mean now for how it could be wrong in a circumstance i have not tested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

- Your assignments should not be enclosed in a constructor of a type.
- The expression in your conditional for the `if` statement is always `True` because `'Y'` is always `True`. Use the `lower()` method on the string variable if you want to compare strings case-insensitively.
- The `if` statement for your zipcode comparison is indented one level deeper than it should.
- The value of `zipcode` is a string, since it is the returning value of the `input()` function. You should therefore compare it to a string rather than an integer.

With the above issues fixed, your code should look like:

```
deliveryValue= input("Is this order for delivery? Y/N")
DeliveryTime = 0
zipcode = None
DeliveryFee = 0
if deliveryValue.lower() == 'y':
    address = input ("what is the delivery address?")
    zipcode = input ("What zipcode is the address in?")
    if zipcode == '84041':
        DeliveryTime = 30
        DeliveryFee = 6.50
    else:
        DeliveryTime = 45
        DeliveryFee = 7.50
else:
    DeliveryFee = 0
```